# Create reverse DNS for Azure Cloud VM when using AzureResourceManager (ARM) mode

Tags: azure, dns, reverse, azure-resource-manager

I have created VM using AzureResourceManager (ARM) mode. I want to configure reverse DNS record for my VM, BUT, all instruction are for AzureServiceManagement (ASM) mode, like https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/ 
The main error is that command Set-AzureService is not working, also  Set-AzureRmService command is not working. So, how can I create Reverse DNS using ARM commands?

Comment: Are you using Powershell or Templates? (or the Portal)

Answer (score 1):

For VMs created with the ARM management stack, you need to set the Reverse DNS property on the Public IP Address resource (PS reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt603620.aspx), and API reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163590.aspx)) associated with the VM/LoadBalancer. As with ASM, you need to demonstrate at create time that you own the DNS name to which you want the reverse DNS record to point - you can achieve that by specifying the Reverse DNS value to match the fully qualified DNS name (ends with a dot) for the Public IP Address.

Regards,
Stephen Malone - Azure Networking